# Why should I encapsulate objects in using if there is garbage collection

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I was searching this on the internet and with no success. So hopefully someone here can answer me this because I don't understand the point of it.

- Is it just good practice or it actually does something?
- Why should I bother if .NET has very good garbage collector?

## Example

In this example I will use super-simple data-annotation validation filter. What is the benefit of encapsulating my data context in `using`?

```
public static ValidationResult ValidateUniqueUsername(string username, object context)
{
    using (var db = new MainDataContext()) // What's the point?
    {
        var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);

        if (user == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
        return new ValidationResult("Username already taken");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many previous SO questions available on this topic answering these exact queries... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655902/using-and-garbage-collection and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it et. al.

Answer (score 2):

The `using` clause basically unwraps to this:

```
ISomeDisposable disposable = new SomeDisposable();
try
{
    // your code here
}
finally
{
    if(disposable != null)
        disposable.Dispose();
}
```

So, as you can see, if your code throws an exception, the disposable object is Disposed.  If you don't thrown an exception, it is still disposed (hence the use of the `finally` block).  It *ensures your object is disposed*.

Answer (score 1):

A `using` block is just syntactic sugar for a `Try...Finally` block. So your code is the equivalent of this

```
MainDataContext db = new MainDataContext();
try
{
   var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);

   if (user == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
       return new ValidationResult("Username already taken");
}
finally
{
    if (db != null)
      ((IDisposable)db).Dispose();
}
```

This means that regardless of the `return` call, db's `Dispose` method is called (because it's in a `finally` block). Generally speaking it's always a good idea to dispose of any object that implements `IDisposable` whether it's managed or not; although there are a few exceptions.

In a managed scenario this may or may not be too important, although I recommend sticking with best-practice, but `Dispose` is primarily used for `unmanaged` resources. These resources can remain thus causing a memory leak which is why it's a good idea to dispose of them when you've finished using them. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx):

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.
>   The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a
>   managed object when that object is no longer used. However, it is not
>   possible to predict when garbage collection will occur. Furthermore,
>   the garbage collector has no knowledge of unmanaged resources such as
>   window handles, or open files and streams.

Answer (score 1):

Some objects are Disposable. That means they use external resources (Files pointer, sockets) that arn't in the GC scope (lower level resources).

These resources need to be disposed (freed) before the object that hold them is destroyed. They can cause a memory leak if the object is removed by the GC whithout calling the dispose method before.

The using block take care of calling the dispose automaticly at the end of the block.
It is similar to:

```
Obj obj;
try{
      obj = new Obj();
      //code
}
catch(Exception e){
      //error
}
finally{
      obj.Dispose();
}
```

The Obj class must implements the Disposable interface to be disposable. An using block can't be used with a non-disposable object (at least in C#).

It is generally a good pratice to use disposable object inside an using block.

Comment: Except it isn't as your code would swallow the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating the data in **"using"** makes sure that the object is **disposed off** as soon as it is out of the "using" scope.

Garbage collector, on the other hand, disposes an object, when it determines that the object is out of scope or when **no longer needed**.

In MSDN's way: Using Provides a convenient syntax that **ensures the correct use** of IDisposable objects.

As the other answer says, @(Moo-Juice)

> "it ensures your object is disposed."

Answer (score 0):

First - read about [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) pattern and its purpose. Note the first sentence:

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.

That's the point. [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) is about realising the memory **not resources**. Here is where [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) comes with help. Read the chapter Manipulating Unmanaged Resources of [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#conditions_for_a_garbage_collection). Notice, that:

> If your managed objects reference unmanaged objects by using their native file handles, you have to explicitly free the unmanaged objects, because the garbage collector tracks memory only on the managed heap.

[Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) is an undeterministic mechanism. You can declare a finalizer in your class but you can't be sure when it will be called. Therefore your unmanaged resources can be hold without any reason.