# What about the using construct in c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, using

I see this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt"))
{
     // d0 w0rk s0n
}
```

Everything I try to find info on is does not explain what this doing, and instead gives me stuff about namespaces.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to check out documentation for the [*using statement*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) (instead of the *using directive* which is about namespaces).

Basically it means that the block is transformed into a `try`/`finally` block, and `sw.Dispose()` gets called in the finally block (with a suitable nullity check).

You can use a using statement wherever you deal with a type implementing `IDisposable` - and usually you *should* use it for any disposable object you take responsibility for.

A few interesting bits about the syntax:

- You can acquire multiple resources in one statement:

  ```
  using (Stream input = File.OpenRead("input.txt"),
         output = File.OpenWrite("output.txt"))
  {
      // Stuff
  }
  ```
- You don't have to assign to a variable:

  ```
  // For some suitable type returning a lock token etc
  using (padlock.Acquire())
  {
      // Stuff
  }
  ```
- You can nest them without braces; handy for avoiding indentation

  ```
  using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("input.txt"))
  using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("output.txt"))
  {
      // Stuff
  }
  ```

Comment: Why would I want to dispose instead of being lazy?  Is it like uber garbage collection?

Comment: @Joshua: To clean up after yourself - you don't want to leave open file handles for example.

Comment: Why don't they auto-close at the end of the scope in the destructor?

Comment: Like how do I know which kinda objects to use this on?  Any object??

Comment: @Joshua: the scope defines the minimum lifetime, not the maximum lifetime. It's a garbage-collected language; the collector can run any time it feels like.

Comment: @Joshua: Because C# doesn't have deterministic finalization. Are you a C++ developer? It's worth being *very* clear about the difference between native C++ object lifetimes and those in .NET - where the garbage collector may well wait a while before collecting objects.

Comment: @Joshua: As for which objects - you *can* use it with anything that implements `IDisposable`. You *should* almost always use it for objects which your code "owns" (typically by creating it) which implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Yes I come from C++ where cleaning after yourself is a MUST and EVERYWHERE.  I guess what you're telling me is here in C# seems it is ONLY in SOME places....  I just need like a list of those places!

Comment: Anything implementing `IDisposable` would qualify as one of those places ;)

Comment: @Nate - not quite...  See http://blogs.msdn.com/kimhamil/archive/2008/11/05/when-to-call-dispose.aspx for a good summary.

Comment: @kvb: I don't think those are good guidelines. Better: if you create it, and use it entirely within the scope of a method, and it implements `IDisposable`, and if it's not a WCF proxy instance, then `Dispose` it. You may get away with not disposing `DataSet` and such things that only implement `IDisposable` because they inherit `Component`, and Mr. Richter may be right about Pens and Fonts, but anything else is taking too many chances. You need to ask, "why not"?

Comment: @John - you can certainly quibble with the specific guidelines.  I just wanted to highlight that it's not as simple as "Call Dispose on anything implementing IDisposable".  Unfortunately, there are a significant number of subtleties.

Comment: @kvb: I believe there's only one "subtlety" that's actually harmful in general, that's the WCF proxies. All the others I've read about are, at worst, a waste of time. In general, I'd rather give out a blanket statement and have the resources cleaned up, rather than the opposite.

Answer (score 10):

The using construct is essentially a syntactic wrapper around automatically calling dispose on the object within the using.  For example your above code roughly translates into the following

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.text");
try {
  // do work 
} finally {
  if ( sw != null ) {
    sw.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is answered by section 8.13 of the specification.

Comment: C# 3 specification: http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc

Comment: Haha. I was about to downvote for an unhelpful answer, but then I noticed who it was. I suppose you're allowed to get away with answers like that.

Comment: @Simon: There simply is no substitute for reading the specification. That's what *I* do when I have a question about the language.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Basically, it automatically calls the Dispose member of an IDisposable interface at the end of the using scope.

Answer (score 0):

check this [Using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: @Hun1Ahpu: please try to give out only current references to MSDN. I fixed your link.