# C# possible mistaken empty statement

Tags: c#

In C#, I can write something like:

```
using (new MyDisposableClass().MethodA());
```

The semicolon causes a compiler warning to be shown which states possible mistaken empty statement. I haven't run the above code but won't the method still be called?

What uses is there of this type of coding convention? I saw another thread on here about this but I ask in case there areny differences now/therefore different replies.

Thanks

Comment: what do you try to achieve with this clause?

Comment: The point of using is that the clause defines the variable(s) and that the body is where you use said variable(s) to perform some actions. If you used the statement the way it was intended, you wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: @unholysampler: not `variable`, but `reference`

Comment: Here ; is used intentionally, you can use #pragma to turn off this warnings

Comment: @unholysampler IMHO the point of `using` is that it defines a scope in which you use a disposable resource, and then automatically disposes it. You don't necessarily have to assign it to a variable, as demonstrated in ASP.NET MVC - `using (Html.BeginForm()) { ... }` (Instead of explicitly calling `Html.EndForm()`)

Comment: @zerkms: I meant object reference. I was just being lazy and using the terms interchangeably. @Daniel Schaffer: My point still holds for the `BeginForm` example because the method returns the disposable object and `Html.EndForm` is a helper method that calls the `EndForm` method of the object that gets called when it is disposed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this code basically translates to

```
MyDisposableClass tmp = new MyDisposableClass().MethodA();
try
{
}
finally
{
    if( tmp != null )
        tmp.Dispose();
}
```

Basically you're disposing the result of the call to `MethodA`, rather than disposing of the `MyDisposableClass` which is the likely intent.

The `;` following the using statement is legal but the warning suggests that you might have added it there by mistake. For example the following code won't compile:

```
using( var tmp = new MyDisposableClass() );
{
    tmp.MethodA();
}
```

The parser evaluates two entirely separate blocks and is seen by the compiler as if you had typed this:

```
using( var tmp = new MyDispoableClass() )
{

}


{
    tmp.MethodA();
}
```

It's easy to miss a dangling `;` by eye so the compiler warning is simply suggesting that you probably meant to do something else. There are times when the shorter concise statement is desired and I think the best way to indicate that it is on purpose is to use `{}` instead of a `;`.

```
using( new MyDisposableClass().MethodA() ){}
```

Note still that this is disposing the result of the call to MethodA - not the MyDisposableClass instance. Your code should actually be written as

```
using( var tmp = new MyDisposableClass() ){ tmp.MethodA(); }
```

Comment: This is only assuming that `MethodA()` returns a `MyDisposableClass`

Comment: @Daniel - it wouldn't have to be a MyDisposableClass - just IDisposable.

Comment: No, this: `MyDisposableClass tmp = new MyDisposableClass().MethodA();` would require that `MethodA` returns a `MyDisposableClass`.

Comment: Ummm....that's a translation of the original code - doesn't make any assumptions about the class definition. The rest uses var which would only require IDisposable.

Answer (score 3):

The using statement can be used as the opening for a clause, at the end which an instantied object is disposed of. In other words:

```
using (var foo = new bar())
{
  SomeStatments();
} 
//foo is disposed
```

or

```
using (var foo = new bar())
  SomeStatments();
//foo is disposed
```

Your semicolon isn't ending the `using` statement. It's actually ending an empty clause following the `using` statement. This is often not the programmers true intent. Thus, the compiler issues a "possibly mistaken empty statement" warning.

**Update**: Assuming the code you listed in the question is actual code, then you should probably turn `MethodA` into a `static` method, since you obviously are not enforcing a constraint or relying on any class members.

Answer (score 2):

Why try to be clever?

This should be equivallent and future developers won't have to google what the briefer syntax might mean.

```
//By the name of the example, I can assume that MyDisposableClass 
//implements IDisposable
using (MyDisposableClass something = new MyDisposableClass())
{
   //Assuming the example code compiles, then the return value of MethodA
   //implemented IDisposable, too.
   using(something.MethodA())
   {

   };
}
```

And if you need to dispose of something after only one call, why not make MethodA do the clean up of what ever needs to be cleaned up?

Comment: Are you sure it's an equivalent? `using` expect references to objects as argument, but he passed the result of `MethodA`

Comment: The example names confuse the matter.  It looks like MyDisposable won't get disposed and the return value of MethodA() will be disposed.  I'll update my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be clearer to write this:

```
using (var myDisposable = new MyDisposableClass())
{
   myDisposable.MethodA();
}
```

The way you have it, the result of `MethodA` would actually be getting treated as the `IDisposable` implementation.

Comment: And you know that is not the questioner's intent because...?

Comment: My assumption is based on the fact that the class he's instantiating is called `MyDisposableClass`. It could be that he wants to apply the using statement against the result of `MethodA`, but I suppose the larger issue is that the intent isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe helps this sample:

```
public static class Helper {
    public static void Using<T>( Action<T> action ) where T : IDisposable, new() {
        var obj = new T();
        action( obj );
    }
}

// ...
Helper.Using<MyDisposableClass>( cls => cls.MethodA() );
Helper.Using<OtherClass>( cls => {
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { cls.DoRandom(); }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be tempted to use this style.  It does call the method.  But it is an idiom at best, and is more likely to confuse the next reader - including you, in several months - than it is to enlighten.

Even replacing the ";" with an empty block (which eliminates the compiler warning) might lead to head-scratching when read later - and remember that code is *read* more often than it is written.

Paul Alexander's answer is correct, but I don't have sufficient reputation to comment on it.

I have used it on an occasion where I was just interested in the side effect of an exception being thrown from the method:

```
try {
    using (var _ = File.Open(logPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) { }
} catch (Exception ex) { ... }
```

File.Open returns a FileStream which must be closed or disposed.  But I didn't really like it.  I ended up naming the variable and putting an explicit Close in the block.  I felt it would be easier to understand, later.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes compiler warnings are generated, then not cleaned up when you keep typing. Try building the solution, and see if it goes away.

Also, I'm not sure what comma you're referring to. Do you mean the semi-colon at the end of the line?

Answer (score -2):

This method will essentially call MethodA() and then never use it. 'Using' uses whatever is in the parentheses only within that specific using block. Then it goes out of scope. So:

```
using (new MyDisposableClass().MethodA())
{
    //Code that uses MethodA()
}
```

...should not give that error, but MethodA() will still be inaccessible outside the using block.

Clarification:

You can still call `new MyDisposableClass().MethodA()` elsewhere in the program, but the specific call made within the code `using (new MyDisposableClass().MethodA())` will go out of scope and be inaccessible.

Comment: The using block is used to specify when you want an item that uses resources to be disposed. After the code in the using block is executed Dispose() is called on the object and the object essentially goes out of scope. If you type "using (a = new disposableObject()){}" then you will not be able to access 'a' anywhere else other than in the using block. If you declare it then not use it (i.e. "using (a = new disposableObject());") then the compiler will throw that warning. Maybe I did not explain this correctly, but I have the right idea in mind. The -2 I think is unnecessary.

Comment: Here is an explanation of 'using': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: Oh, now I see my error. 'using (new MyDisposableClass().MethodA())' produces a warning because there is no object set to be used. Got it.