# Error in Update query [Using String.Format]

Tags: sql-update, string.format

I am trying to write an update statement for inserting data from asp.net gridview to sql server 2005 database.but it is showing me an error, Please tell me how to solve.

```
cmdUpdate.CommandText = String.Format("Update Products SET ProductName=
{0},UnitsInStock={1},UnitsOnOrder={2},ReorderLevel={3} WHERE ProductID={4} AND 
SupplierID={5}", "productname.Text, unitsinstock.Text, unitsonorder.Text,  
recorderlevel.Text, employeeid.Text, supplierid.Text");
```

Error is-
Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Where the quotes for the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the arguments,

For instance,

```
str=String.Format("{0} {1}",arg1,arg2);
```

Do not use [hard-coded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) sql strings. Try to learn/use parameterized queries.

EDIT:

```
string ConnectionString = "put_connection_string";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        string sql = "Update Products SET 
                ProductName=@ProductName,
                UnitsInStock=@UnitsInStock,
                UnitsOnOrder=@UnitsOnOrder,
                ReorderLevel=ReorderLevel 
                WHERE ProductID=ProductID AND SupplierID=@SupplierID";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =productname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitsInStock", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value =unitsinstock.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitsOnOrder", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value =unitsonorder.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReorderLevel ", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value =recorderlevel.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value =producteid.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupplierID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value =supplierid.Text;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: What is C# using block?

1. [If the type implements IDisposable, it automatically disposes it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)
2. [Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)
3. [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx)

Comment: Can u please show me an example for my above qyery<BR/> do i need to use stored procedure with input parameters or I can simply use text type of queries.<br/>

Comment: >Thanks a lot for your comment.> I always use to thought this way is used with Stored Procedures only. like this one        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SearchResult",con);
        cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtInputRollNo.Text;

Comment: @AVD---I always used to write programs like 

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnectionString"]);
 con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SearchResult",con);
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RollNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtInputRollNo.Text;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

But why, some people used to write using “using”..

Like

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for string.Format is incorrect - each parameter after the string template should be on their own, without the double quotes surrounding them all...

This will work (notice I've removed the double quotes from just before 'productname.Text' and after 'supplierid.Text'):

```
String.Format("Update Products SET ProductName={0}, UnitsInStock={1}, UnitsOnOrder={2}, ReorderLevel={3} WHERE ProductID={4} AND SupplierID={5}", 
    productname.Text, unitsinstock.Text, unitsonorder.Text, 
    recorderlevel.Text, employeeid.Text, supplierid.Text);
```