# Having problems trying to connect to local SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2010 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble trying to connect to a local database. I've tried some of the suggestions from other posts on this site but to no avail. Any help will be appreciated. Below is what I have so far.

```
private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        sConnection = "Server=(localdb)\Database1;Integrated Security=true;";

        dbConn = new SqlConnection(sConnection);
        dbConn.Open();

        sql = "SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER" +
            "BY Customer name ASC;";
        dbCmd = new SqlCommand();
        dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
        dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

        dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dbReader.Read())
        {
            aMember = new member(dbReader["Name2"].ToString());
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(aMember);


        }

        dbReader.Close();
        dbConn.Close();
    }
    catch (System.Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 Express *LocalDB*, then you connection string should be something like: `Server=(localdb)\v11.0;database=Database1;Integrated Security=true;`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here that I can think of. I'll address two.

#### 1. Connection String

You're wanting to connect to "Database1" as a Database and not an instance. Try changing your connection string first. 
Change sConnection to this:  
`string sConnection = "Server=(localdb);Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=true;";`

#### 2. Using statement ([Benefits of it...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057334/when-should-i-use-the-using-statement))

```
        var sConnection = "Server=(localdb);Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=true;";
        using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sConnection))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            using (var cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY [Customer Name]";

                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        aMember = new member(reader["Name2"].ToString());
                        this.listBox1.Items.Add(aMember); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the problem.

```
sConnection = "Server=(localdb)\Database1;Integrated Security=true;";
```

Check this

```
sConnection = "Server=(localdb)\\Database1;Integrated Security=true;";
```

> Beginning in .NET Framework 4.5, you can also connect to a LocalDB
>   database as follows:
>
> **`server=(localdb)\\myInstance`**

Check this [**docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Don't get the reason for downvote or reason for a recommended deletion.

Answer (score 0):

As marc_s mentioned: The correct connectionstring is "Server=(localdb)\v11.0;database=Database1;Integrated Security=true;"

Comment: If you're putting that in a string you need either `@"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;..."` or `"Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;..."`.