# Data type mismatch in criteria expression Access 2013

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert-update

```
OleDbCommand computerStatus = new OleDbCommand("update Computer SET Status= 'Occupied' where PcNumber='" + cboComputerNo.Text + "'", con);
computerStatus.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

this is my code. pcNumber is autonumber i am getting an error it wants me to change the data type to string but i need it to be autonumber.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection.  Use int.TryParse to convert your text to a number.

Comment: already used TryParse and int.parse did not work for me 1st time using parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AutoNumber`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoNumber) is auto **number**. Since it is a numerical value, you don't need to use single quotes with it.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand computerStatus = con.CreateCommand())
{
    computerStatus.CommandText = "update Computer SET Status= ? where PcNumber = ?";
    computerStatus.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Occupied");
    computerStatus.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", cboComputerNo.Text);
    computerStatus.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

As LarsTech pointed, you may wanna check your `cboComputerNo.Text` string is a valid integer with using [`Int.TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx).

Comment: why do i need to use using? why not make it smaller in code?

Comment: @AllanPatrickCaldito Using statement dispose unmanagement resources. Check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057334/when-should-i-use-the-using-statement and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it