# error at int records = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); illegal variable name/ number

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I'm getting an error on this line of code:

```
int records = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Error is:

> Illegal variable name/ number

Complete code:

```
string strq = "select count(*) from groupmembers where group_members='" + txtgrpmem.Text + "'";
cmd = new OracleCommand(strq, Dbconn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("group_members", txtgrpmem.Text);

if (Dbconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    Dbconn.Open();
}

int records = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (records == 0)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your query needs to include group_members parameter like this:

```
    string strq = "select count(*) from groupmembers where group_members=:group_members";
```

Note: The parameter name is prefixed with colon (:)

Comment: The leading `@` is for **SQL Server** - as far a I know, **Oracle** doesn't use that syntax

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you've used the parameter `group_members` with your `OracleCommand` but you haven't used the parameter in your query. Check here for [Parameterised Query](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html). Also, check in the link for `OracleCommand.ParameterCheck`

```
string strq = "select count(1) from groupmembers where group_members=:group_members";

using (OracleConnection Dbconn = new OracleConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
   if (Dbconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
      Dbconn.Open();
   }

   using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strq, Dbconn))
   {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("group_members", txtgrpmem.Text);

       int records = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   } 
}
```

Also, [why using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057334/when-should-i-use-the-using-statement)