# Using 'using' in front of StreamWriter

Tags: c#, using, streamwriter

I'm doing a tutorial on how to save a text file with StreamWriter. I understand how to do it but I started reading a tutorial on the StreamWriter Class to get a better understanding of it. In an example, it places the word using StreamWriter but in the other tutorial, it does not.  Why is this? Do I need to use the using?

how to save to text tutorials way

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter("data.txt", true);

            File.Write("");
            File.Close();
        }
```

==  StreamWriter Class In C# With Programming Example  ==

```
namespace StreamWriter_Class
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = @"D:\csharpfile.txt";
        --->    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
```

Comment: Using `Using` will allow for automatic garbage collection. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10057366/1350913)

Comment: Using is used for classes that implement IDisposable. It is the same as wrapping the block of code in a try/catch/finallyblock and running the .Dispose method in the 'finally' section. If you don't do this, it can cause memory leaks. Using is the preferred way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. There are a lot of good tutorials out there, but they don't explain the little things like that too well or at all.

Comment: @DanielShillcock that is a mis-statement; `using` doesn't impact the garbage collection **at all**. Disposal is different to collection.

Answer (score 2):

`using` is a syntactic sugar that makes sure that the resource you are using (no pun intended!) will be `Dispose()`d , no matter if the actions that were performed on it threw any exception (which is not uncommon when handling external resources).

WHile it's not strictly "wrong" not to use it, it's a very good practice, and you should probably adopt it wherever possible.

See [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

Every `using` will become something like that:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
try
{
    // do something with writer
}
finally
{
    if(writer != null)
        writer.Dispose(); // close handle and free resorces
}
```

Always your `writer` handle and resources will be closed and free and GC don't need to check that.

You can use `using` in yours own classes implementing `IDisposable` interface.

See:

> https://www.dotnetperls.com/using
>
> [When should I use "using" blocks in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567138/when-should-i-use-using-blocks-in-c)
>
> [Implementing IDisposable correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336856/implementing-idisposable-correctly)
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally

Comment: Close, except the variable is declared outside the try so that it has scope in the finally...

Comment: Yes, you're right @michael. Edited

Comment: Close again, the assignment is done in the try... but the declaration is done outside.

Answer (score 1):

`using` will make sure that the object (in this case `StreamWriter`) will be disposed, when it is out-of-scope.

There are posted plenty of examples with explanations in this question:
[What are the uses of "using" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/what-are-the-uses-of-using-in-c-sharp)

And here is a really good explanation from DotNetPerls:
[DotNetPerls - Using](https://www.dotnetperls.com/using)