# Unable to access the Microsoft Access database using asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

This is code i wrote to add some text to accordion pane on a button click:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Use a string variable to hold the ConnectionString.
        string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
            + "Data Source=D:\\C#Samples\\StudentDetails\\WebRole1\\App_Data\\Students1.accdb";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection cn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = connectString;
        //Create an OleDbConnection object, and then pass in the ConnectionString to the constructor.
        //OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            //Open the connection.
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AccordionPane1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Open Error"));
        }

            string selectString = "SELECT * FROM BasicInfo";

            //Create an OleDbCommand object.
            //Notice that this line passes in the SQL statement and the OleDbConnection object
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, cn);

            //Send the CommandText to the connection, and then build an OleDbDataReader.
            //Note: The OleDbDataReader is forward-only.

            try
            {
                OleDbDataReader reader=null;
                try
                {
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (Exception es)
                {
                    AccordionPane1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" datareader"));
                }
                string s = "s";
                reader.Read();
                s = reader["S_No"].ToString();

                AccordionPane1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(s));
                //Close the reader and the related connection.
                reader.Close();
                cn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AccordionPane1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" Read Error"));
            }
    }
```

I have my access 2007 database in the folder i specified in the connectString. When im viewing in the browser, on the button click i am getting all the three exceptions:
[image]

What might be the problem in opening the database? Do i need to make any other changes?

Comment: Could you provide text of the exceptions?

Comment: You sir are swallowing the exceptions and that's why you can't debug and expect us to play the guessing game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;

to

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            + "Data Source=D:\\C#Samples\\StudentDetails\\WebRole1\\App_Data\\Students1.accdb
```

Hopefully it will solve the issue.

Comment: The above connection string is correct for the .accdb format (2007/2010), which is what the OP is using.

Answer (score 1):

you connection string might be cause of isssue

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\abc.mdb;";

OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
```

this **For access 2007** also check the path of database is cocrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|DataDirectory|` *instead* of `real path` and you have to change the `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` (as suggested by @MMK)

```
 string connectString = @"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
       Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Students1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

and always use `using` block which dispose *IDisposable* objects properly.

```
using(OleDbConnection cn=new OleDbConnection())
{
 using(OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand())
 {
  cn.ConnectionString=connectionString;
  cmd.CommandText=selectString;
  cmd.Connection=cn;
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But i didn't get the reason why should we use "using". Can you please explain me

Comment: @Pramod - Read - [What is the C# Using block and why should I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)