# Does the C# `Using` statement close the variable if an error happens inside the using clause

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, idisposable, using, spweb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the C# Using block and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)

If I ran the following code:

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("/myweb")){

   //error happens here
}
```

Would the object `web` be disposed of properly **if an error occurred before the closing bracket?**

We were told that using `using` statements for our `OpenWeb` object was the best but
we are seeing a lot of errors in the logs about SPRequests and SPWeb.

Comment: `Would the object web be disposed of?` **YES**

Comment: Apologies, @L.B didn't finish my thought, corrected the question.

Comment: and **YES** for `Would the object web be disposed of properly **if an error occurred before the closing bracket?**`

Comment: I suppose we are getting a lot of erroneous error logs then.

Comment: @iambriansreed what makes you think the error logs are erroneous?

Comment: Many, many duplicates of this question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idisposable+using-statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, that's kind of the whole point.  It's syntactic sugar for:

```
SomeType obj = new SomeType();
try
{
    // do stuff with obj
    // if an exception is thrown then the finally block takes over
}
finally
{
    if(obj != null)
        obj.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: That's what I was told and always believed but we appear to be getting a lot of errors regarding the SPWeb.

Comment: @iambriansreed: Either the C# compiler is broken or the bug is somewhere else.  I'd suspect the latter.

Comment: I was told `SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb` should never be disposed. Is that true as well?

Comment: Note that if the `Dispose` implementation of SPWeb throws an exception, that will *not* be handled.

Comment: @iambriansreed: I am not familiar with the SharePoint API, so I have no idea.  Read the documentation.  That said, it would seem to be correct as that object is probably intended to stick around.  You don't own it.

Comment: The C# compiler will also do a null check on `obj` before calling Dispose, but yes this is pretty much correct.

Comment: @iambriansreed You should not dispose of the current context's site/web, that's correct.  It's not that the items shouldn't be disposed, it's that you're not the one repsonsible for disposing it.  The current context will create a site/web, hand that same object to a number of requests, and then handle disposing of it after a while.  If you dispose of it early than all of the other requests that were given the same site/web will break, and have no knowledge of why.

Comment: @Servy Your comment has led me to my next question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54483/is-using-the-using-statement-to-close-random-webs-bad-practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See MSDN for a full explanation of exactly what "using" does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Short answer is yes, since the Dispose is in a finally clause.

Comment: There's no `catch`, it's just a `try / finally`

Comment: Was updating the post as you commented, you are correct.