# Use of C# using keyword in a user defined class

Tags: c#, using-statement

Everybody knows that using keyword is used when we want to clean up the unmanaged resources.

If the class implements `IDisposable` then we can use `using` keyword with the object of that class.  But if I want to use `using` keyword with the object of my own class then how can I use it.

If I had to implement `IDisposable` in my own class then I  have to also write the code for its `Dispose()` method in my class.  Then there is no point of using the `using` keyword here when I am writing my own code in `Dispose()` method.  Then how can I use using in a user defined type (like classes & structs).

Please explain with some example.

Comment: Less of the down votes folk. This is just a learning curve for some people!

Comment: so much for helping each other. I wonder of 6 downvotes add a lot...

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the question. I don't understand the down-votes.

Comment: I am not going to write an example down, as you would be better just reading this article. [Implementing IDisposable and the Dispose Pattern Properly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P) - on the Code Project website.

Answer (score 5):

The point of the `using` keyword is that it *calls* `Dispose()` on the instance of your class for you, so you don't have to write `myDisposableObject.Dispose()` yourself when you're done using it. It doesn't help you *write* that method — you still have to write it yourself to tell the framework how exactly you want your unmanaged resources to be disposed.

I'm not sure what kind of example you're looking for, since you clearly know how to implement the `IDisposable` interface and its `Dispose()` method. All I can say here is if you don't have any unmanaged resources to dispose (or members that are themselves `IDisposable`), then don't implement `IDisposable`, and don't use `using`. That keyword is reserved only for conveniently using things that *do* have unmanaged resources that would otherwise need manual cleanup.

Comment: To be clear, classes can also implement `IDisposable` if they contain other _managed_ resources that are `IDisposable` (e.g. Timer, Stream, etc.)

Comment: @Eren Ersönmez: Ah, yes. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Note that `using` doesn't just call `Dispose()`, it places it in a finally block and adds a null-check.

Answer (score 2):

The point of `using` is not to relieve you from implementing `IDisposable`.

The point of `using` is to allow you to ensure that the object will be properly disposed when the flow exits the block either normally or due to an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `using` statement calls the `Dispose` method of the the used object upon termination of the block. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14637152/836432) to see how a using block is compiled.

However, it is your responsibility to implement the `Dipose` method, in which you have to free the resources occupied by the object.