# How to output data from form selection after connecting to DB - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, forms

I have the following SP:

```sql
ALTER proc [CRM].[s_CRM_GetEmail]
(
    @EmailTemplateID int
)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN @EmailTemplateID = 1 THEN 'This is EmailTemplate 1'
        WHEN @EmailTemplateID = 2 THEN 'This is EmailTemplate 2'
    END AS EmailBody
    FROM [CRM].[CRMData]
    WHERE CRM_ID = 1 
END
```

The following is my webform:

```html
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Type" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">Select Email Template:</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Bike Template</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Car Template</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
        <p><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="OK" /></p>

</form>
 <textarea name="'emailbody" rows="20" cols="100"/> </textarea>
```

Lastly, the following is my code thus far:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=Server_Logistics;Integrated Security=True";
         con.Open();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String id = Type.SelectedValue;
            int emailid = Int32.Parse(id);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CRM.s_CRM_GetEmail", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailTemplateID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = emailid;

                using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(rdr["EmailBody"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I want to extract the contents based upon user drop-down box selection.  So far I've got it to connect to DB but I'm not sure how to extract the data and display. Ideally I want to extract it in the textarea on the webform, but either way just want to extract data.  I would be grateful for any guidance.

I've got it to finally extract! I've replaced Console.WriteLine(rdr["EmailBody"]); with Response.Write((rdr["EmailBody"])); Next question is is there a way to get this populating in the textarea on the webform?

Comment: I've got it to finally extract!  I've replaced Console.WriteLine(rdr["EmailBody"]); with Response.Write((rdr["EmailBody"]));  Next question is is there a way to get this populating in the textarea on the webform?

Comment: You need to better understand the [life cycle of an asp.net form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)). Then you can start to better understand how a POST operation works and how to handle populating control values with data on postback.

Comment: As a side note if you are building something new then I would strongly recommend you take a step back and learn MVC or learn an SPA framework instead. ASP.NET webforms is considered legacy framework by microsoft. It is only good for maintaining and extending existing code basis.

Comment: thanks for your comments @igor.  It's really something the business want quick and I don't have the skills to deliver.  I am proposing to learn MVC and SPA frameworks, but for now just wanted a quick, easy solution.  I feel I'm nearly there, got the correct data extracting after user selection just wanted it displaying in the textarea.  I know it something to do with the property settings and pointing to it, but not sure how at the moment.

Comment: Add `runat="server"` in your `textarea` in the `.aspx` form as well as an `ID`. Now you can access it from your code behind in the postback and set the value.

Comment: That's amazing @igor exactly what I was trying to work out.  So do I set it by something like emailbodywrite = (rdr(["EmailBody"]));? emailbodywrite being the textarea id

Comment: Never mind fixed it - emailbodywrite.InnerHtml = rdr["EmailBody"].ToString(); in case anybody was wondering.

Comment: **See [C# Data Connections Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552829/c-sharp-data-connections-best-practice)**