# Not able to closed db connection if it's being user by some other process in c#

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

```
connection = CreateDBConnetion();
try 
{
    _ = ExecuteQuery(connection, query);

    OtherProcess();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Error
    // DB update opertions
}
finally
{
    connection.close()
    // Others
}
```

In the above code when some error occurred in `otherProcess` method and DB connection is still being used by `ExecuteQuery` method then while closing connection In finally block not working properly and also not throwing any exception. Not moving forward from from `connection.close()` and still `ExecuteQuery` method running in the background.

Any idea why it's not allowing me to closed connection while it's being used by some other process.

Comment: Don't create it at class level. Create the db connection _in the method_ and dispose it there also. Also read up on `using` rather than `Close`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Data Connections Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552829/c-sharp-data-connections-best-practice)

Comment: I know that we should use `using` for batter practice but actually, I need DB connection in catch block also for DB update if any error occurred. I will update in my example code block.

Comment: Put the `try catch` _inside_ the `using`.

Comment: Already tried it but still not able to close the connection when it's being used somewhere else