# Why do I get the error "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'Form.QueryExecute' to 'string'." when creating a DB connection in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to architect the structure of code for a DB connection. I've created a class which I called 'DbConn.cs':

```
class DbConn
    {
        public SqlConnection getDbConnection()
        {
            String connectionString = "Data Source=172.26.187.34, 1181;Initial Catalog=LoansDev;User ID=AppUser;Password=Passw0rd";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            return conn;
        }

        public bool isConnectionEstablish()
        {
            try
            {
                getDbConnection();
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return false;  
            }
        }
    }
```

Now every time I try to execute a query I'll just call the class `DbConn conn = new DbConn();` then I'll use the conn.getDbConnection().open() to open and connection and vice versa. I don't know if it's a proper way of handling connections since all tutorials I've seen is the handler for connection is also where the query is being executed.

Now I have a class 'QueryExecute.cs' which will hold all my queries.

The problem is if try to call the method on my form, I always get the error

> "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'Form.QueryExecute' to 'string'.

Here is the code for my form:

StatusViewForm.cs:

```
private void StatusViewForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           // frmLogin loginForm = new frmLogin();
            //String loggedUser = loginForm.getUserID;
            //MessageBox.Show(LoggedUser, "Who is logged in?", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            QueryExecute taskEmp = new QueryExecute();
            DbConn dbConn = new DbConn();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            String userID = taskEmp.getEmployeeDetails(userID: LoggedUser);
            String query = taskEmp.getTaskDetails(LoggedUser);
            //MessageBox.Show(query, "Query", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, dbConn.getDbConnection());

            dbConn.getDbConnection().Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dbConn.getDbConnection().Close();

            dgvTaskView.DataSource = dt;

        }
```

Then here is my QueryExecute.cs:

```
public QueryExecute getEmployeeDetails(String userID)
        {
            DataTable empDetails = new DataTable("EmployeeDetails");
            QueryExecute empInfo = new QueryExecute();
            DbConn conn = new DbConn();

            using (conn.getDbConnection())
            {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee WHERE UserID = '" + userID + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn.getDbConnection());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userID);

                conn.getDbConnection().Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                da.Fill(empDetails);

                if(empDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    empInfo.UserID = (string)empDetails.Rows[0]["UserID"];
                    empInfo.Name = (string)empDetails.Rows[0]["Name"];
                    empInfo.IsAdmin = (bool)empDetails.Rows[0]["IsAdmin"];
                }
                conn.getDbConnection().Close();
            }
            return empInfo;
        }
```

I'm wondering if it's my DbConn class that is causing the problem...

Comment: You return a QueryExecute instance from getEmployeeDetails and try to assign it to the string userID. QueryExecute  is not a string. And @TimSchmelter is right about your DbConn class. Its not only a bad pattern your implementation is also useless. isConnectionEstablish does not check if there is a connection established.

Comment: Also getDbConnection returns everytime a new connection. So everytime you call open close on that connection its everytime a different connection that wasn't used but leaks resources.

Comment: So It's better to just call the connection everytime I execute a query?

Comment: Yes. It does not hide information. It makes clear who is responsible for resources. And reusing of a connection is not usefull. The system does connection pooling in the background. You get that for free.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"? There are many "proper" ways to do it... the thing they all have in common is that they work.

Comment: This is definitely *not* the way to do connections, you create a new connection, *use* that connection, and dispose it with a `using` block. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552829/c-sharp-data-connections-best-practice