# Can not add data model into my project. C# WPF MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datamodel

I am using MySql as my project database. I am trying to add a data model to my project but as soon as I finish the steps, it goes back to the first page. can someone please help me with what to do?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**and after last step, the first step just comes up.
I also check connection on step 3 and it was working.**
Thank you guys.

Comment: [Similar problem solving](https://www.cnblogs.com/dupeng0811/p/solve-your-project-references-latest.html) Author: dupeng0811. Does it help you?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I tried it but does not work. It is VS2012 and I have 2019. Also in his problem in last step he does not have Entity Framework, but i do.

Comment: I have inquired a lot of information, this may be a problem with `MySQL`  , because I did not encounter this problem with `SQL` . [Alfredo Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241500/cant-create-entity-data-model-using-mysql-and-ef6/60927974#60927974) or [Connect Entity Framework with MYSQL in VS2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386441/connect-entity-framework-with-mysql-in-vs2019) . Does it help you?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I just tried these steps and it does not work + it doesn't even let me go to the last step now. it just closed and go to first step :-(

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I have serious complication with this problem, and I am new and its getting near to my dead line each day it pass :-( do you know anyone by chance that can help me with this problem? it would be really nice.

Comment: Just have a try. [Entity framework database provider compatibility error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565780/entity-framework-database-provider-compatibility-error) My work machine does not have Mysql, so I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT it's not working :-( IDK if it's ok with you, you can try to come and check it on Discord or Anydesk or however you know :-(  I really do need it :-(