# write file name with parameter inside for loop

Tags: c#, streamwriter, streamwriter.write

I want to create a list with all the numbers between 0000000 - 9999999 and to create a new file every 50000 rows.

I tried this code:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\numbers" + fileparam + ".txt"))
{
    for (counter = 0 ; counter < 10000000 ; counter++)
    {
        if (counter < 10)
        {
            file.WriteLine("000000" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 9 && counter < 100)
        {
            file.WriteLine("00000" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 99 && counter < 1000)
        {
            file.WriteLine("0000" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 999 && counter < 10000)
        {
            file.WriteLine("000" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 9999 && counter < 100000)
        {
            file.WriteLine("00" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 99999 && counter < 1000000)
        {
            file.WriteLine("0" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 999999 && counter < 10000000)
        {
            file.WriteLine(counter.ToString());
        }
        if (counter % 50000 == 0)
        {
            fileparam++;
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't work, because it already opened with the "fileparam" that was initialized at the start of the program "int fileparam = 0;" and i got 
"numbers0.txt"

I also tried this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\numbers" + fileparam + ".txt"))
{
    for (counter = 0 ; counter < 10000000 ; counter++)
    {
        if (counter < 10)
        {
            file.WriteLine("000000" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 9 && counter < 100)
        {
            file.WriteLine("00000" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 99 && counter < 1000)
        {
            file.WriteLine("0000" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 999 && counter < 10000)
        {
            file.WriteLine("000" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 9999 && counter < 100000)
        {
            file.WriteLine("00" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 99999 && counter < 1000000)
        {
            file.WriteLine("0" + counter.ToString());
        }
        else if (counter > 999999 && counter < 10000000)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file2 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\numbers" + fileparam + ".txt"))
            {
                file.WriteLine(counter.ToString());
            }
        }
        if (counter % 50000 == 0)
        {
            fileparam++;
        }
    }
```

and all the files after numbers0.txt were empty.

Comment: This doesn't answer your questiob but you don't need all those if statements. You can pad 0's to your number like this `file.WriteLine(counter.ToString().PadLeft(7,'0'))` or `file.WriteLine(counter.ToString("0000000"))`

Comment: Is this what you *actually* need to do, or is your real work doing something different in terms of the data? The exact approach I'd take would depend on the situation - you may be able to "batch" the data, collecting everything you need to write to each file separately, then iterate over that "collection of collections", writing one file per collection.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var counter = 0;
var fileParam = 0;
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(string.Format("C://archive/Numbers/numbers{0}.txt", fileParam));

while (counter < 10000000)
{
    sw.WriteLine(counter.ToString("D7"));
    if ((counter + 1) % 50000 == 0)
    {
        fileParam++;
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        sw = new StreamWriter(string.Format("C://archive/Numbers/numbers{0}.txt", fileParam));
    }
    counter++;
}

sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Nice, but I can offer a couple of improvements: first, use counter.ToString with a format instead of creating new strings: counter.ToString("D6") [(see this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros). Second, instead of writing the strings one by one into the StreamWriter I think a better solution in this case will be to use a StringBuilter and write to the file using File.WriteAllText on each fileParam change.([read here])(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988457/streamwriter-vs-stringbuilder) I admit I'm not sure about the second one.

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware of that format option. I updated my answer. I don't know whether a StringBuilder is better, I'll do a performance test and let you know, you are probably right :-)

Comment: almost no difference, stream: 12147 ms, StringBuilder 12902 ms