# How to create .data file in c#

Tags: c#

I want to create .data file in C# in the following format: -

```
#Section Name

data
data
data

#Section Name

data
data
data
.
.
.
```

Can anyone help me out in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I tried to create this file by using StreamWriter class, but while using this class, it gives me "The file is being used by another process" error. I am more concerned about the formatting of the file.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far. Formatting the file should be pretty easy. StreamWriter is a good approach, you just need to format the string you write into the file with `String.Format`

Comment: show us the code you are doing so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to open the file more then once inside your code, that would lead to such exception. 
Another approach is using a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of using `StreamWriter` to write the content, and then just use [`System.IO.File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to write the content of the `StringBuilder` to a file.
Using a `StringBuilder` will probably have higher memory use but lower IO use then using a `StreamWriter`. for more details, [read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988457/streamwriter-vs-stringbuilder)

Here is how I would do it using a `StringBuilder`:

```
string FilePath = "c:/temp.data"; // this should hold the full path of the file
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Of course, you should use your one code to create the data, 
// this example is purely based on your format description.

sb.AppendLine("#Section Name").AppendLine();
sb.AppendLine("data");
sb.AppendLine("data");
sb.AppendLine("data").AppendLine();

File.WriteAllText(FilePath, sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a stream with `FileShare.ReadWrite` options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).