# I want to integrate Textbox in my query. After hours of searching the internet, I came across the following code. Is there any better solution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, parameterized

'code

```
Dim conn as SqlConnection = new SqlConnection("SERVER=LOGIC\SERVERDB;DATABASE=sample;User=sa;Pwd=codename")
conn.Open()


Dim userId as String = txtUserId.Text
Dim sql as String = "SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE id=@userid"

Dim cmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommendText = sql
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid", userId);

Dim dr as SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: This looks like the best way to do it. Also, parameterised queries are always recommended when you are taking input from user for the query.

Comment: that should work; a better way *overall* would be to include the Password hash in the SELECT query.  If you get nothing back, then one of the values is wrong...saves testing the PW value.

Comment: consider to use `Using` for your `SqlConnection`, its make sure they dispposed at the end. `Using conn As New SqlConnection("SERVER=LOGIC\SERVERDB;DATABASE=sample;User=sa;Pwd=codename")`

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor changes if your're happy to adopt:

`SqlConnection` implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx). Try wrap it with a `Using` block, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it) is why.

Not sure if you use your name and password somewhere later. If its not used in the later part, why not just send in as param and `SELECT Count`, then [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)?

If `userId` is used only once, I would reduce a line of code without declaring the variable

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection("SERVER=LOGIC\SERVERDB;DATABASE=sample;User=sa;Pwd=codename")
    conn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT name, password FROM users WHERE id=@userid"

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", txtUserId.Text)

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()            
End Using
```