# Do I need to close connection when using a 'using' statement

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

Currently my code is constructed as follows.

```
using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Context.ReturnDatabaseConnection()))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();

            try
            {
               //Code here

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

Ideally from what I understand using the 'using' statement will take care of the connection being closed but I have my doubts due to what other people have said.

Thanks

Comment: `using` calls `Dispose` on the object when finished. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326260(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Can you provide links to those other answers with conflicting opinions? I'd say no close is needed, you can remove that entire `finally` block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NO need as object will automatically disposed when we use `using` blocks. Go through this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

[What is the C# Using block and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

Hi just the using statement will be fine. It will dispose the object and generally requires less coding.

Answer (score 1):

The using will take care of it for you. As additional background, a using statement is syntactic sugar for a try ... finally that disposes the IDisposable object in the finally.