# How to get alert when Unique key is violated

Tags: c#, alert, unique-key

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=VIVID-PC;Integrated Security = True;Database=SchoolDb");
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Command String", myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();

        string firstText = TextBox1.Text;
        string SecondText = TextBox2.Text;
        string thirdText = TextBox3.Text;
        string fourthText = TextBox4.Text;



        myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SchoolDb_Student(StudentName,RollNo,Session,MobileNo)values('" + firstText + "','" + SecondText + "' , '" + thirdText + "','" + fourthText + "')", myConnection);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConnection.Close();

        Response.Redirect("/view.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) detected. Use command parameters

Comment: sorry, i cant get you. Help me in specific i am a beginner.

Comment: you can click on link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Use command with parameters to pass data to server](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06).
2. Make sure you dispose connection and command ([via using statement](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using))
3. [Store connection strings in config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
4. Do not create dummy command objects

Here is complete code:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = 
       @"INSERT INTO SchoolDb_Student(StudentName,RollNo,Session,MobileNo)
         VALUES (@studentName, @rollNo, @session, @mobileNo)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("studentName", TextBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("rollNo", TextBox2.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("session", TextBox3.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("mobileNo", TextBox4.Text);

    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(SqlException e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Contains("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint"))
            // you got unique key violation
    }
}
```

Further considerations - improve naming in your code - TextBox1, TextBox2 etc says nothing to reader. Give them appropriate names, like StudentNameTextBox, RollNoTextBox etc. Also good practice is splitting data access and UI logic.

Answer (score 0):

If the database detects a unique key violation, this line

```
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

will throw an exception. You can catch that exception and proceed with your own code:

```
try
{
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // right here, "something" went wrong. Examine e to check what it was.
}
```

Please note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should be using command paramaters instead of building the SQL manually. In addition, you should be using `using` blocks ([see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it))

Answer (score 0):

[ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will throw an exception if it's unable to INSERT row into database. In your case, it's most likely an [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Catch it.

Comment: thnks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

use your [returnType from ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Read the remarks part) to detect failure in insertion. you can use the exception or the no. of rows affected part

Try this :

```
try
{
... your rest of the code
...
int rowsAffected = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Most probaboly it will throw exception in case of Unique key violation. If not, still no rows have been affected
if(rowsAffected<1) 
{
    //your Alert for no records inserted
}
else
{
    //your alert for successful insertion
}

}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
//check the exception and display alert
}
finally
{
   //release connection and dispose command object
}
```

Comment: anytime buddy, Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment use command param.

```
try
{
   //Your other code 
  _myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   myConnection.Close();
   Response.Redirect("/view.aspx");
}
catch(SqlException sqlExc)
{
 // Your popup or msg.
}
```

You also loop for different sql error in catch block.