# How to delete Zip file after copying into another folder

Tags: c#, .net

how to delete a zip file after copying into another folder...I am getting exception while deleting..It is saying that "The file is being used by another process".

```
string pathString1 = FullFilePath;
string sourceFileName = Path.GetFileName(pathString1);
string foldername = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathString1);
string pathString = Path.Combine(foldername, "Uploaded");
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, sourceFileName);
    File.Copy(pathString1, destFile);

    File.Delete(pathString1);
    File.Delete(FileName);
}
```

Comment: Provide the code you're using to work with the files.

Comment: Show the code you tried to get help.

Comment: You need to close the stream you are using to read the file. Once we can see your code we can help.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: Where does the curly bracket in your code go? There is just one lone one

Comment: It may be that the file is open in an antivirus type of program.

Comment: Actually when i am giving text files the file is deleting..but when i am giving the zip at delete getting exception

Comment: how can I close the stream?

Comment: because you say it is a problem with a .zip and not a .txt, makes me think it is a virus checker that you may have to wait for

Answer (score 2):

If you decompress the zip-file, then do this in a using block or .Dispose() the object that is responsible for decompressing. What lib are you using?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the locking of files, the [using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it) statement will release the file  when it's done with the operation:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open("path to file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    ...
}
```

Then again, if you're deleting the file right after you copy it, then why not just move it?

```
File.Move(from, to);
```

Comment: tried but der  also same exception.. could not access because the file is being used by another process..

Answer (score 0):

since there is this theory that a virus checker goes into your .zip file, you could re-try waiting for it to finish with retries

```
string pathString1 = FullFilePath;
string sourceFileName = Path.GetFileName(pathString1);
string foldername = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathString1);
string pathString = Path.Combine(foldername, "Uploaded");
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, sourceFileName);
    File.Copy(pathString1, destFile);

    int itries = 0;
    int maxtries = 30;    //suitable time of retrying
    while (itries++ < maxtries)
    {   
        try 
        {
            File.Delete(pathString1);
            itries = 999999;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          if (itries > maxtries) throw ex;  
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }       

    }

    //File.Delete(FileName);
}
```