# Multiple TransactionScope.Complete() in a using

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

I have a code like this

```
try
{
    MyModel model = repo.GetData();
    if(model == null)
    {
       return model;
    }
    else
    {
       MyResponse response = checkData();
       if(response)
       {
           return model;
       }

       UpdateData();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    ....
}
return model;
```

I want to add `TransactionScope` like this.

```
try
{
   using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
    {
        MyModel model = repo.GetData();
        if(model == null)
        {
            return model;
        }
        else
        {
            MyResponse response = checkData();
            if(response)
            {
                return model;
            }

            UpdateData();
        }
        ts.Complete();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    ....
}
return model
```

And I wanna ask, is it okay if I have multiple `return` statement before code reach `ts.Complete()`? I can't set `ts` into null in `finally` block because `TransactionScope` is inside try block.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: is it ok to return before trans.Complete()? - Yes, it is. Transaction will not be commited and changes will not be applied. That is how it works.

The using statement will run .Dispose() in any senarios even when an exception is happening (or return).

When disposing a transaction it will be committed if trans.Complete() was called, and no changes will apply if not called.

About using statement:
[What is the C# Using block and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)

About Transaction.Dispose():
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx