# Nested Using statements affects performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, ado.net, using

```
     using (var db1 = new DataBase1Entities())
        {
           using (var db2 = new DataBase2Entities())
           {
                var list = (from obj in db2.Table1
                            where !db1.Table2.Any(i => i.Table2Col == obj.Table1Col)
                            select obj).ToList();
           }
        }
```

does anyone know how to retrieve value from one database table and compare it with another database table ? If the above code is correct, then will it cause performance issue ?

Comment: Nested `using` is common pattern to use multiple `IDisposable`s.

Comment: It's not `using` but resource allocation/freeing that affect the performance; another resource consuming process is the code inside `using` - "code to retrieve data from db1 and compare it with db2"

Comment: "affect performance" relative to what? Obviously *having code* will *take time to execute*. **What exactly is the question here?**

Comment: `"affect performance" relative to what` Based on the context, presumably compared to not using nested using. i.e. have the second `using` **outside** of the first.

Comment: i have editted my question.

Comment: they are in different database

Comment: What type is `db1`? Or: which ORM is this? For the rest: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: What are the sizes of the `Table1` and `Table2`? What is the expcted fraction of the `Table1` after filtering?

Comment: Did either answer work for you @DineshM ?

Comment: no it didnt work.. since i have bulk records in both the tables in different database. i need to get the records from one database table first and compare it with another database table. Is there any other easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 5):

You seem not to know [what a `using`-statement does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212210/1997232). Effectively it´s nothing but a try-finally-block where within the finally there´s a call to `Dispose`. So your code is translated to the following:

```
DataBase1Entities db1 = null;
try 
{
    db1 = new DataBase1Entities();
    DataBase1Entities db2 = null;
    try 
    {
        db2 = new DataBase2Entities()
        // do something with db2
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(db2 != null) db2.Dispose(); }
    }
}
finally
{
    if(db1 != null) db1.Dispose();
}
```

So it´s not the `using` that may or may not have an effect on performance, but the `Dispose`. However you shouldn't bother for that at all, as you *have* to call `Dispose`. Doing not so is a really bad idea - in particular if it´s done because of any performance-issues. `Dispose` will release any unmanaged resources, e.g. file handlers. If you´re not calling it there´s no way to release those resources at all which will probably produce memory-leaks.

Comment: I don't know, but +1 from me.

Comment: don't know neither, but because of that +1 from me too.

Comment: if you check for `null` the code should be `DataBase1Entities db1 = null; try {db1 = new DataBase1Entities(); ... } finally {if(db1 != null) db1.Dispose()};`. Local variables (`db1`, `db2`) are *not initialized* with `null`, that's why `if(db1 != null)` doesn't sence in the current code

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You´re right. Corrected appropriately.

Comment: That's nice `using {...}` pattern explanation, +1

Comment: I didn't downvote, but neither do I think that because of an unexplained downvote people should upvote. Try to understand the downvote instead. Like: this may be a nice explanation, but it doesn't answer the question(s).

Comment: I did upvote, but not because there was a downvote or a missing reason for a downvote - In my opinion the question doesn't make sense (sorry!) and this answer could help the OP understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly remove the nesting if you wanted to. Something like (untested):

```
HashSet<YourType> bob;

using (var db1 = new DataBase1Entities())
{
    bob = new HashSet<YourType>(db1.Table2.Select(z => z.Table2Col);
}

using (var db2 = new DataBase2Entities())
{
     var list = (from obj in db2.Table1
                 where !bob.Contains(obj.Table1Col)
                 select obj).ToList();
}
```

You'd need to profile it to check whether it was any faster. *Much of the speed benefit, if any, would likely be due to the use of the `HashSet` rather than the removal of the nested using.*