# Alternative To Multiple using Blocks

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In all the examples I see for Entity Framework data access, every method has its own `using` block, as shown below.

Is there an alternative to this approach? For example, can the context object just be a class member, such as:

```
MyModelContext context = new MyModelContext();
```

Is there a reason why a new context object has to be created for each method in the DAO class?

```
public class DaoClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
         using (var context = new MyModelContext()) 
         {     
             // Perform data access using the context 
         }
    }

    public void DoAnotherThing()
    {
         using (var context = new MyModelContext()) 
         {     
             // Perform data access using the context 
         }
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
         using (var context = new MyModelContext()) 
         {     
             // Perform data access using the context 
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: You could push the responsibility to dispose up to the consumer by instantiating the context as a field during construction, implementing IDisposable on the DaoClass, and making sure all consumers are properly disposing of it. In your current case, each method is responsible for provisioning and disposing of it's resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the `DaoClass` implement `IDisposable` and have the context be a property of the class. Just make sure to wrap `DaoClass` in a `using` statement or call `Dispose()` on the instance of the `DaoClass`.

```
public class DaoClass : IDisposable
{
    MyModelContext context = new MyModelContext();

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // use the context here
    }

    public void DoAnotherThing()
    {
        // use the context here
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        // use the context here
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the only benefit of the `using` statements in my original post is the disposal of the object? Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. `using` statements are just syntactic sugar. It wraps the statement in the parenthesis in a `try...finally` block and calls the object's `Dispose()` method in the `finally` block. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/212210/4416750).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the `context` object is the equivalent to a database **transaction**.

It implements the `IDisposable` interface because a transaction must be closed when done with and you either have to use the `using` statement or make an implementation of `IDisposable` like Lews Therin demonstrated.

We use multiple instances of a `context` object to separate different transactions. There will be cases when you want all changes to go as a single transaction and either commit all together or rollback everything. Then you put it all in one `context` instance. But there will also be cases where you want to separate the saving of one data pack from another. Then you use different transactions, i.e. different `context` objects.

To get a better grasp of this chapter take a look at the *unit of work* pattern.

Hope I could help, merry coding!

Comment: Note that while a DbContext instance is intended to support a UnitOfWork, it is a bigger scope than a database transaction.  You might fetch data, work on it in memory and finally save it to the database in your UnitOfWork.  This would be too long-running for a database transaction.  I might be better to describe the scope as a "business transaction".

Answer (score 0):

The way you show it is how I've seen it recommended everywhere. I've seen there be weird issues with class level declaration returning stale or incorrect data.

To get around duplicating all the code I like to write an execute method that I can reuse, or make changes without having to go to every using.

```
   private T Execute<T>(Func<MyModelContext, T> function)
        {
            using (MyModelContext ctx = new MyModelContext())
            {
                var result = function(ctx);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return result;
            }
        }

  public List<Type> GetTypes()
        {
            return Execute((ctx) =>
            {
                return ctx.Types.ToList();
            });
        }
```