# Hey I need more information about this code

Tags: c#

```
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 string start = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Sav1.txt";

 using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(start)) {
  string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

  int[] values = line.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

  Array.Sort(values);

  Array.Reverse(values);

  for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
   richTextBox4.AppendText(values[i] + " ");
  }
 }
}
```

Hey guys I need more information about this code. Could anyone explain me how it works. I mostly googled it so dont know how it works. Also I have added .txt file and got access to first row, but i need to get into 7 and 8 row. There's just random numbers in that .txt file.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? How about copying and pasting the classes, methods and properties into an internet search tool. The names of things (like `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` and `Array.Sort`) seem pretty obvious.

Comment: Which part of the code specifically don't you understand?

Comment: Hey, Yeah code works perfectly, but i just get access to first row of .txt file. I understand some of it. Only dont know about        using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(start)) {
  string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

  int[] values = line.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah idk how does using works why i need to do that new StreamReader()

Comment: @Tom See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there's a better way to do this. `StreamReader` has a `.Peek()` method that is extremely useful for reading to the end of a file. Basically the only thing you're missing is a way to loop through each line in your file.

### Start with your using statement.

```
   using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(start)) {...
   //Using statement is a way for you to close your stream after the work
   //is completed. This is why you need to get a loop inside of here.
```

### Use a loop to read to the end of a file.

*This part is what I'd change in your code. Your `Using` statement will not loop. You have to tell it to loop. `Peek()` returns -1 or the next character to be read. So you can use this to your advantage to check if you want to read to the end of file. Review the documentation here.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.peek?view=netframework-4.8

```
while(streamReader.Peek() > -1)
    {...
```

### Then you can split to your array per line by simply reading in each or splitting to a character.

```
int[] values = streamReader.Readline().Split(' ');
```

### Finally you can do the remainder of your code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
    richTextBox4.AppendText(values[i] + " ");
}
```

To break down exactly what is going on in your code. Read each comment line by line to get a basic understanding.

```
//Button Click Event
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

//Finding your file and assigning it as a string. 
 string start = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Sav1.txt";

//Using a `using` statement and creating a new streamReader that will look
//for the string that you created above to find the file. The using block
//will properly close the streamreader when the work is done. 
 using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(start)) {

//StreamReader.ReadLine() will read the FIRST line, no loop here.
//This is why your code only reads one.
  string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

//Splitting to an array. 
  int[] values = line.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

//Sorting array.
  Array.Sort(values);

//Reversing the array. 
  Array.Reverse(values);

//Looping through the array based on count. 
  for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
   richTextBox4.AppendText(values[i] + " ");
  }
 }
}
```

If you're attempting to only get rows 7, 8, 9, etc.. within your for loop at the very end of your code do the following.

```
//Looping through the array based on count. 
      for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
       //This will only append rows 7-9. Keep in mind an array is a 0 based
       //index. Meaning row 7 is actually array element 6. Row 9 is actually
       //array element 8. 
       if(i > 5 && i < 9){
           richTextBox4.AppendText(values[i] + " ");
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hey @xTwisteDx thnx for help, I got one more question. So i did like u said added that while (streamReader.Peek() > -1)
    {...                                                        and i debugged all .text i got. But i only need 7-8-9 rows. Tried some thing but didn't worked.

Comment: thanks a lot xTwisteDx !

Comment: @Tom please take the time to mark my answer as the correct answer if I helped. I'm trying to boost my reputation on the site. If it wasn't sufficient, please let me know so I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So my current code looks like this:

```
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            string start = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Sav1.txt";

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(start))
            {
                while (streamReader.Peek() > -1)
                {

                    string[] values = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(' ');

                    Array.Sort(values);

                    Array.Reverse(values);

                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    {
                        richTextBox4.AppendText(values[i] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
```