# SQL | C# - Reader rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, methods

I have a small problem with MySqlDataReader. I have data in MySql and I have column "name" and X rows under. Reader reads sucessfully all of this but output is in one string and looks like "FirtSecondThird" but i need all of this words in list word by word. The code is:

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                vystup.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
            string out1 = "";
            foreach (string outage in vystup)
            {
                out1 += outage + "\n";
            }
            return out1;
```

Does anyone know what to do with it? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__)

`string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine,  vystup);`

Comment: @styx still i have "FirstSecondThird".

Comment: Can you send me exactly where should i use string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine,  vystup);? @StefanWuebbe maybe i am only stupid. Thanks

Comment: @KvetinskyStepan instead of the `foreach` loop you can return the `string.join` result

Comment: `MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cmd, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                out1 = reader.GetString("name");
                vystup.Add(out1);
            }
            return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, vystup);`

Comment: is it right? @StefanWuebbe // Sorry for format of the code..

Comment: Hm, how does @styx ' Answer not show hat you want?

Comment: Otherwise I'd also ask What's `vystup` content, type , where is it coming from?

Comment: @KvetinskyStepan just show us `vystup`  content

Comment: @StefanWuebbe yes. It works! Thanks. I marked his answer as correct

Comment: By the way your connection, command, and reader objects need to be disposed with `using`

Comment: @Charlieface what do you mean?

Comment: I can use `connection.Dispose(); 
             command.Dispose();
             reader.Dispose();`

Comment: Yes but a `using` block ensures that `Dispose` is called even in the event of an exception. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it

Comment: I changed in all methods from `MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cmd, connection);` to `using MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cmd, connection);`. With reader i do same change and i added line `connection.Dispose();` @Charlieface

Comment: You don't need `Dispose` or `Close` because `using` does that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0)

if `vystup` is a `List<string>` which contains the following items
"first", "second","third"

then
outputting `string.join(Enviorment.NewLine, vystup)`
will yield

"first"

"second"

"third"